# How can I get a sum of the total time in each presentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, sum

The goal is to have a count of how many presentations are used, plus the total amount of time for all the presentations. I currently have the total count which is `<%= sale.lead.presentations.count %>`.

What I'm trying to figure out is how can I add up the total sum of this variable: 
`(<%= distance_of_time_in_words(presentation.started_at, presentation.ended_at, include_seconds: true, scope: "datetime_abbr.distance_in_words") %>)`

Below is how I currently have this formatted:

```
<% sale.lead.presentations.each do |presentation| %>

            <div>
              <strong><%= presentation.name %></strong></br>
              <%= presentation.started_at.in_time_zone.to_s(:nice_time) %> -
              <%= presentation.ended_at.in_time_zone.to_s(:nice_time) %></br>
              (<%= distance_of_time_in_words(presentation.started_at, presentation.ended_at, include_seconds: true, scope: "datetime_abbr.distance_in_words") %>)
            </div>

          <% end %>
```

This is my current output:

**SL 2700 Window Sales Manual 8.19 v7**
10:59p - 11:06p
(6 mins and 41 sec) - <---I want the total sum of this for all presentations

Answer (score 0):

I think best way to do it is put a method in your controller where this view is prepared. Code can be like

```rb
def (where_your_view_is_prepared)
  ...
  @total_presentation_time = 0
  sale.lead.presentations.each do |presentation|
    @total_presentation_time += (presentation.ended_at - presentation.started_at)
     # => This will give something like this 128184857/28800000000
  end
  @total_presentation_time = (@total_presentation_time * 24 * 60 * 60).round
    # => This will give you the total seconds of presentation
    # => You can also use this Time.at(285).utc.strftime('%H:%M:%S') will give result "00:04:45"
  ...
end
```

or if you want to normalize time object for every presentation itself you can do it like this

```rb
def (where_your_view_is_prepared)
  ...
  @total_presentation_time = 0
  sale.lead.presentations.each do |presentation|
    @total_presentation_time += ((presentation.ended_at - presentation.started_at) * 24 * 60 * 60).round
     # => This will give something like this 285
  end
  # => Can be directly use in both controller or in view
  ...
end
```

After you get the total_seconds either from first method or second method you can also format it by yourself like this.

```rb
def format_presentation_duration
    hours = @total_presentation_time / (60 * 60)
    minutes = (@total_presentation_time / 60) % 60
    seconds = @total_presentation_time % 60
    "#{ hours } hours #{ minutes } minutes and #{ seconds } seconds"
end
```